# automatic download from server to my server

Tags: java, linux, httpurlconnection, wget

a supplier of mine delivers his price list with a link like this:

http://www.example.com/report?cad1=104516005&cad2=da97172291f241855399358471275b38

If using a browser, you go to this address, the server generates a excel report  on the fly and a "Save as..." dialog appears so you can download it, like this:

[image]

I was told to make a cron job, so the file would be transfered to my server automatically every day, and I really don't know if that's even posible.

I tried using java's HttpURLConnection, but I get a "503 Forbidden" message when I try to connect to that URL, plus, the file itself doesn't really exist on the server, and if it exists, I don't know the location of the file.

I also tried using linux wget, but it returns the html from this address (http://www.example.com/report) instead of the excel file that is generated.

Is there a way to do this using java or any other thing that can be executed as a cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer need an answer for this. The requirements changed.

I'm answering the question since I cannot delete it.